# Regex does not match the intended line

Tags: python, regex

I use the regex `fault-filtertime 5(.*)! TH` to match everything between and including `fault-filtertime 5` and  `! TH`. However this does not work for some reason. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Please provide *details*. Input, expected output, what 'does not work'? We can all go and guess here, but with more information we could give you a more definite answer.

Comment: use `fault-filtertime 5(.*?)! TH`

Comment: I really don't understand the down votes here.. Is it just becauseI didn't provide "details" ?

Comment: @Cemre: most probably, yes. The term 'this does not work for some reason' is vague in extreme. There are millions of ways things might not work, you need to define what that means in this context. Answer the following questions for yourself: What would it look like if it *did* work? What does it look like *instead*?

Comment: @Cemre: And now you have a second answer below, that applies a *different* guess to what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a multiline data, or including other control characters, you need to use `re.DOTALL`, like this:

```
import re

data = """
fault-filtertime 5
foo
bar
baz
! TH
"""

regex_str = "fault-filtertime 5(.*?)! TH"
regex = re.compile(regex_str, re.DOTALL)
result = re.search(regex, data)
print result.group(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `*` modifier is greedy, it'll match the maximum it can match if you let it. If there is more than one occurrence of `! TH` in your input text, the `.*` will match everything up to the *last* occurrence.

Use `*?` instead to switch off greedy matching; `.*?` will match the *minimum* number of characters instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('fault-filtertime 5(.*)! TH', 'fault-filtertime 5 foo bar baz! TH fault-filtertime 5 spam ham eggs! TH').group(1)
' foo bar baz! TH fault-filtertime 5 spam ham eggs'
>>> re.search('fault-filtertime 5(.*?)! TH', 'fault-filtertime 5 foo bar baz! TH fault-filtertime 5 spam ham eggs! TH').group(1)
' foo bar baz'
```